# Overwrite a sheet in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to overwrite one sheet of my excel file with data from a .txt file. The excel file I'm bringing the data into has several sheets but I only want to overwrite the 'Previous Month' sheet. Every time I run this code and open the excel file only the previous month sheet is there and nothing else. Many solutions on here show how to add more sheets, I'm trying to update an already existing sheet in an excel with 8 sheets total.

How can I fix my code so that only the one sheet is edited but all of them stay there?

```
import pandas as pd
#importing previous month data#
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx')
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Previous Month', startrow=4, startcol=2)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Edited code- whatever is happening here keeps corrupting my original file

```
import pandas as pd 
import openpyxl
#importing previous month data#
writer=  pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', mode= 'a', engine="openpyxl", if_sheet_exists="replace")
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Previous Month", startrow=2, startcol=4) 
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace'` within `pd.ExcelWriter` yet?

Comment: @BigBen I just posted my edited code where I do include everything in your comment. For some reason it is corrupting my file and when I open the excel file it says I need to recover it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What versions of openpyxl/pandas do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `openpyxl.load_workbook()` to do what you are looking for. While I did try the above suggestions, it didn't work for me. the `load_workbook()` usually runs without issues. So,  hope this works for you as well.
I open the output file using `load_workbook()`, deleted the existing sheet (`Sheet2` here) if it exists, then create and write the data using `create_sheet()` and `dataframe_to_rows` ([Ref](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.4/pandas.html#working-with-pandas-dataframes)). Let me know in case of questions/issues.

```
import pandas as pd 
import openpyxl

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t')

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('output.xlsx')  # Open workbook
if "Sheet2" in wb.sheetnames:  # If sheet exists, delete it
    del wb['Sheet2']

ws = wb.create_sheet(title='Sheet2')  # Create new sheet

from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True) # Write dataframe as rows

for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
         ws.cell(row=r_idx+2, column=c_idx+4, value=value) #Add... the 2, 4 are the offset, similar to the startrow and startcol in your code
            
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```